# hide url get parameter but should be accessible in subdirectory htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, get

I have an url http://example.com/folder/file?name=plumber&id=32&counter=2&count=3

I want an url http://example.com/folder/file/plumber/32/2/3

But all these value should be accessible from $_GET['']

I know it is done with htaccess but whatever the solution i tried i failed to access get values.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It's a good idea to share what you have tried already, what you expected to happen, and what failed.  Then people may be able to help fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following rewrite rule may help:

```
RewriteRule ^luigi/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$ index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2&baz=$3 [L]
```

There are lots of similar examples to be found on-line and on stack overflow.

Comment: I tried much more solution that are available on stack overflow but non of the solution worked for me.

Comment: Did you have any joy adapting this?

Comment: Sorry mate this is not the solution that helped me

Comment: RewriteRule text_area/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ text_area.php?job=$1&id=$2&counter=$3&count=$4   this solution worked form me but in a condition the htaccess file i have created inside the folder where the file exist